# How to seed using faker in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have user model having field name,pass,email, and so on.
**User Factory**

```
$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ];
});
```

**DatabaseSeeder**

```
public function run()
    {
        // $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(UserSeeder::class);
    }
```

**UserSeeder**

```
public function run()
    {
        factory(App\User::class, 2000000)->create();
    }
```

Now I have a friend model and want to seed record into this.
column are sender_id, receiver_id, status(0=pending,1=confirm).
sender_id and receiver_id combine should be unique.
sender_id is user_id and receiver_id is also user_id both ids are from users table.

Can anyone suggest me how to seed data into friends table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Friend Factory**

```
/* @var $factory \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory */

use App\User;
use App\Friend;

$factory->define(Friend::class, function () {

    $senderId  = factory(User::class)->create()->id;
    $receiverId  = factory(User::class)->create()->id;

    return [
        'status' => rand(0,1),
        'sender_id' => $senderId,
        'receiver_id' => $receiverId,
    ];
});
```

**Friend Seed**

```
public function run()
{
    factory(App\Friend::class, 2000000)->create();
}
```

Comment: Above seeder is working properly but unable to create more than one friend for specific user from this code.